# How to makes changes in kal calender to display events from json webservice

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, kal

hi am creating an iphone app in which im using calender in order to display events.For this i used kal calender api  https://github.com/klazuka/Kal in my project and i need to display events based on start date and end date which are coming from json webservice so where  i have to make changes in kal calender project so that i can invoke my start date and end date and display events on that date.Please Provide me the code.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Holiday Example in the Kal git is a good place to start. it also fetchs the events from JSON and shows it in the KalViewController tableView.

**EDIT:**
I can tell you what i did, i had to show the native calender as well as the JSON events in the Kal calenderView

so i did not change any implementation of Kal for fetching the native events but i did add my own fetching method for server events and combined the two arrays.

here's how i did it,
i used the nativeCal example and used the same eventkitDatasource.m as my kal datasource

then, in the KalViewDelegate protocol methood

```
- (void)didSelectDate:(KalDate *)date
```

I sent request to fetch the events from the server for the selected date,
on receiving the events array from server, i then add those objects, to an array in the eventkitDatasource.m, and use that array in the

```
- (NSArray *)eventsFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate
```

to return events from both native calendar and server events.

here is my implementation of the methood

```
- (NSArray *)eventsFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate
{
NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Meeting *meeting in events)
{
    if (IsDateBetweenInclusive(meeting.startDate, fromDate, toDate)){
        [matches addObject:meeting];
    }
}
if([arrServerEvents count]>0){
    [matches addObjectsFromArray:arrServerEvents];
}

return matches;
}
```

also you can see that here i have created a common Meeting class, which has properties of both Ekevent and my server Events. in changed the EKEvents to my common class object in the

```
- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate{
```

methood, and then added these objects to the native events array of the eventkitDatasource.m.

hope I am clear enough.

Comment: im asking how to change the code in datasource method in kal calender